# How to implement one setter for two different objects in JAVA?

Tags: java

Ok guys, just to summarize my experience yesterday, I have to be completely honest with you. I had a job interview with the common technical part. In that job interview I had as much as 10 minutes to refactorize some code in order to improve readability and make it less complex.
But!, I got stuck in the part of setters. Just to put it on the table: we have two objects instantiated from one class that implements an interface.

```
public class test{
  private MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
  private MyClass obj2 = new MyClass();

  public void setGenericMyClass(IMyClass myClass) {
    //insert code here to set obj1 or obj2 in the same method
 } 
}
```

How can I could implement it? In the written test (yes, with a pen) I can use Java 8 or higher.

Comment: What is the goal? To set both obj1 and obj2 to the myClass instance?

Comment: I assume IMyClass is a MyClass and you don't care which one is set?  You could set one at random.

Comment: I honestly don't know what you mean, but if this is the exact test/code you were given, you might not want to work there.

Comment: Set `obj1` or `obj2` based on what criteria?

Comment: @PeterLawrey unless it is meant as I[nterface]MyClass ..

Comment: @khelwood `new Random().nextBoolean()`

Comment: @Stultuske I guess that MyClass is an IMyClass however is MyClass the only implementation?

Comment: @veselin-davidov The goal is pass one of the objects and set it inside the test Class. But, instead of creating two setters, one for each object instantiated, I just have one single setter method.

Comment: @PeterLawrey that was indeed my point :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand the question very well but you should just set both? Define them as interface instance and just give them the new value;

```
public class test{
  private IMyClass obj1 = new MyClass(); //Use interface here
  private IMyClass obj2 = new MyClass(); //Use interface here

  public void setGenericMyClass(IMyClass myClass) {
     obj1=myClass;
     obj2=myClass;
 } 
}
```

Since there is a comment why would you need to store two references to the same object I would give an example. Actually in practice it happens a lot. You need two objects and use use them. If the user of your class wants to pass you the same instance then he might have his reason. Here is a sample code for an office, where you don't want to copy the office machine so you have two objects:

```
class Office {
  private IPrinter printer;
  private IScanner scanner;

  public void setPrinter(IPrinter printer) {..}
  public void setScanner(IScanner scanner) {..}

  void print() { printer.print(); }
  void scan() { scanner.scan(); }

  public void setBigOfficeMachine(IOfficeMachine machine){
    printer=machine;  //IOfficeMachine is an IPrinter
    scanner=machine;  //IOfficeMachine is an IScanner
  }


}
```

Comment: What would be the point of storing two references to the same object? Imo in most cases that would be undesirable. I'd rather make two new copies of the object passed to the method.

Comment: The point is to solve the goal that is asked? Its an interview question it's not a real world scenario. Probably the reason is to show you know what is an interface and you understand how to set your variables ? Who knows.. but that's what he asks. How to set two objects in one method

Comment: @Amongalen sometimes there is a point. Why would you care? Or do you say you shouldnt? If I have a class that multiplies 2 numbers and I want to raise one number to power of 2 why wouldn't I pass the same reference? I added another example in my answer just for you :)